# How do you make this style of text? SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Can anyone tell me how to make such a text style as in the screenshots? I was looking for an answer in Google, then I could not find anything on this issue. This text is used in the application in "TextEditor". Can it be special fonts or can it be done in Swift? Thank you very much for your answer!

Screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2]

Comment: It looks like a custom font.

Answer (score 0):

You can have that text style as a render but not as Font, if you see all the fonts in any language they are in one color, Even if you go and put time to building that font as a custom font, you would not be able to have those fancy colors, unless you start render them as those fonts you want, in this case would be not a text style but a render logic, which needs time and good taste of art.